# Generar correlativo con 5 dígitos usando la función TEXTO - Excel vBA

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()
'
'Dim NombreHoja As String
Dim HojaDestino As Range
Dim NuevaFila As Integer
Dim Uf As Long

'NombreHoja = Me.ComboBox1.Value

Set HojaDestino = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datos_TK").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
NuevaFila = HojaDestino.Rows.Count + 1

'ultima fila



'Set Log = RegistroTickets.lblUsuarioLogR

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Datos_TK")

    Uf = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Cells(NuevaFila, 1).Value = Now 'Fecha/Hora
    .Cells(NuevaFila, 2).Value = Uf - 1 'Numero_Ticket

'''' AQUI DONDE TENGO EL PROBLEMA 

.Cells(NuevaFila, 3).Value = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1("=TEXT(Uf - 1,""00000"")") 'Correlativo_Ticket

'''


    '.Cells(NuevaFila, 4).Value = Log.Value 'UsuarioLog
    .Cells(NuevaFila, 5).Value = RegistroTickets.txtUsuarioAfectado.Value 'UsuarioAfectado
    .Cells(NuevaFila, 6).Value = RegistroTickets.txtArea.Value 'Área
    .Cells(NuevaFila, 7).Value = RegistroTickets.cboTecnico.Value 'Técnico
    .Cells(NuevaFila, 8).Value = RegistroTickets.txtProblema.Value 'Descripción problema
    .Cells(NuevaFila, 9).Value = RegistroTickets.cboEstado.Value 'Estado

    .Cells(NuevaFila, 10).Value = "" 'FechaHora Modificado
    .Cells(NuevaFila, 11).Value = "" 'Usuario Modifica

End With

MsgBox "Alta exitosa.", vbInformation, "SIGEOPS"

Unload Me

End Sub
```

---

¿cómo puedo hacer para generar mi código correlativo de 5 dígitos?

Comment: ¿Qué genera ahora? ¿Qué tipo de problema tienes? ¿Es un error? ¿Están todos los números iguales? ¿Cuál es el input y el output deseado? Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y lee también [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ..

Comment: ahora me sale error con el código mostrado, el input viene a ser codigo autogenerado segun un conteo "UltimaFila" y el output deseado es un concatenado de "00000" 5 digitos por ejemplo: "00005" . Gracias, leeré los links.

Comment: Si quieres generar un número de 5 dígitos, pero que te respete los ceros a la izquierda (por ejemplo, `00005`), no puedes generarlo como número. En Matemáticas, los 0 a la izquierda no tienen valor, y Excel automáticamente los elimina por dicha razón. Si es obligatorio que visualmente se vean ceros a la izquierda, entonces tienes que generarlo como texto, o Excel los borrará. El formato de texto es `@` si no recuerdo mal.

Comment: Gracias @ElierSánchezE-Infantes probaré el formato en texto. Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Example:
if you have in sheet "Sheet1":
A1=5
and
format A2 as personalized  "00000"
then, when run Macro1 you have:
Range("A2")="000005"

Sub Macro1()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 6 - Len(Range("A1")))  & range("A1")
End Sub

Comment: Esto es StackOverflow en español, por favor traduce tu respuesta.